# Unintended commit by Git

Tags: git, git-commit, git-amend

I committed a java file using

```
git commit -a
```

I forgot to add a file to said commit so I tried to amend the previous one using

```
git commit -a --amend
```

When the editor opened up, I changed my mind and closed the editor using `:q!`.

I then did a git log and my unintentional commit was successful.

Anyone know why git went ahead and committed my 'aborted' commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you amend a commit, irrespective of whether you forcefully quit the editor or anything, the amend will be successful as long as the commit message was not empty when the `.git/COMMIT_MESSAGE` file was last saved.

So, with `git commit --amend`, if you previously had a commit message; you'd need to remove the entire message and then save the buffer. When you quit the edit, the amend step will be aborted.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind git commit --amend going ahead and amending the commit?

Comment: @TheCoder The commit hook does not understand your `--amend` flag.

Comment: So my error was combining 2 commands: a commit all + amend my last commit; and git ignored the first one?

Comment: Amending commit and commit all are both same from the perspective of `commit` behaviour. The underlying principle is, amend will load the previous commit message in buffer, and recompute the SHA, thereby generating a new commit (which is what `git commit` does anyway). `--amend` only prepopulates certain values for SHA compute based on previous commit (and removes the same from history).

Comment: Is a commit basically, deleting/ignoring the previous commit, generating a new SHA and giving you the chance to amend the commit message? Or is there something else it does?

Comment: @TheCoder `commit` in itself, records a snapshot of the repo. This snapshot requires author, message etc. parameters and calculates the SHA. On the other hand, the `--amend` flag does the same, but it additionally allows you to overwrite the last commit.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but when you say records a snapshot of the repo, even though I am committing certain individual files, in essence, a commit is creating a new version of the entire project (current state + modifications = new state of repo)?

Comment: Okay, using snapshots was a mistake on my part. https://devdocs.io/git/git-commit `commit` actually "_Record changes to the repository_".

Comment: git records complete snapshots. It's efficient with its dedup, afaik it's in a whole separate league for repo-size tinyness, but each commit is a complete snapshot.   By factory-default setting, commits are only generated if there's a nonempty message, the factory-default message is empty after `#`-comment lines are stripped (another factory-default setting).  To switch back to the previous, unamended commit, `git reset @{1}`.